# Writing output to CSV in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Hey there i'm writing a python script using telethon and i want to store the output into a csv file.

Here is the output and its type:

```
User(id=1266677252, is_self=True, contact=False, mutual_contact=False, deleted=False, ``bot=False, bot_chat_history=False, bot_nochats=False, verified=False, restricted=False, min=False, bot_inline_geo=False, support=False, scam=False, access_hash=2617010733762734224, first_name='Yara', last_name='Ben', username='yaraben', phone='12065826022', photo=UserProfilePhoto(photo_id=4990407516261296244, photo_small=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=107740008, local_id=342263), photo_big=FileLocationToBeDeprecated(volume_id=107740008, local_id=342265), dc_id=1), status=UserStatusOffline(was_online=datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 5, 14, 37, 49, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)), bot_info_version=None, restriction_reason=[], bot_inline_placeholder=None, lang_code=None)

<class 'telethon.tl.types.User'>
```

I have tried some basic csv command but didn't get me anywhere.

Thanks for your help

Here is my code:

```
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsRecent
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import csv

api_id =
api_hash = ''
phone = ''
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()

for user in client.iter_participants('moneymartog', filter=ChannelParticipantsRecent):
    with open("user.csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
        writer.writerows(user)
```

Here is the error i get when i run the code:

```
TypeError: writerows() argument must be iterable
```

Comment: Can you load the data into a pandas DataFrame?  Once there, it’s one function call (`df.to_csv()`) to write to CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) requires argument to be an Iterable, e.g. a List, a Tuple, etc.

Furthermore, there's a lot of objects inside `User` instance, so you probably want to flatten those first (e.g. converting `UserProfilePhoto` object into a string).

That `csv.writer()` is already in your `for` call, probably use `writerow()` for that, probably something like:

```py
for user in client.iter_participants('moneymartog', filter=ChannelParticipantsRecent):
    with open("user.csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow([user.id, user.first_name, user.last_name, "USER" if not user.bot else "BOT", ... ])
```

Comment: thanks a lot you saved me

Comment: sure, you're welcome.